# Can't find the CSS that's causing a right margin

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, underscores-wp

I've been through my CSS like a madman but I can't figure out where the extra right margin of 20 or so pixels is coming in?  The site is at http://goodtimesdjservice.com/ and there's whitespace to the right of the page.  It was themed using the underscore_s framework.  I apologize for he noob question, have tried to find the culprit, and appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="footergroup" class="row footerbg">
```

Has the `row` css class which has `margin-right: 15px`. Getting rid of that will get rid of the space you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this. Set the `max-width:1300px` and override the margin in `.row` for `.footergroup`

```
#wrapper {
max-width: 1300px; /*old value 1400px*/
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: red;
}
#footergroup {
background: #666 url("../img/contact-wrapper.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat-y;
margin: 0px; /*override .row{margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;}*/
}
```

Hope this help you.!

Comment: Thanks a lot to the both of you, my issue was indeed the row which I overrode